# 50k Mexico Topo Maps Sources?

Tags: data

Anyone know of another source (preferably free) for these 50k Mexico Topo Maps other than  [www.omnimap](http://www.omnimap.com/catalog/int/mexico/mex-topo.htm#p1) and [www.eastview](http://www.cartographic.com/hub/index.asp?RegionNameURL=mexico&ProductTypeNameURL=topographic/maps&CategoryNameURL=mexico/50,000/scale/topographic/maps&rid=175&tid=1&sid=19&cid=779&vid=0&oid=0&navmode=r)?

There is a free WMS that has them but only for UTM 15 and 16 here:
http://antroposig.ciesas.edu.mx:8399/arcgis/services/MapotecaDigitalCIESAS01/MapServer/WMSServer

The areas we need are in UTM 12,13,and 14.

[Carta topográfica 1: 50 000](http://mapserver.inegi.org.mx/DescargaMDEWeb/informacion.cem?id=antecedentes)

Answer (score 3):

**Carta topográfica escala 1:50 000**

Three major scales are available:   1:1,000,000; 1:250,000 and 1:50,000.

The DRG maps in the scale of 1:50,000 are being issued and as of today (August 2008) about 85% of the country is available.. They have the same format characteristics as the 1:250,000 ones.

The 1:50,000 maps have shading to help in the terrain contour interpretation.

[image]

There are vector versions of these maps on both  the 1:50,000 and 1:250,000 scales. For the 1:50,000 they are available for 60% of the  country and for the 1:250,000 the whole territory is available.

**The vertical divisions numbered 11 to 16 are the UTM zones in which Mexico lies.**

http://www.bicimapas.com.mx/EnglishEdition/MexicanTopoMaps.htm

http://www.inegi.org.mx/geo/contenidos/topografia/default.aspx

http://www.inegi.org.mx/geo/contenidos/Topografia/Carta50000.aspx

Comment: thanks, i found those links as well but could not find anything with downloading or ordering information.

Answer (score 2):

You may find that the data for many of the World's developing countries are not the greatest.  However, I've found fairly decent data at [VDS Technologies](http://vdstech.com/map_data.htm) the odd time.  I've never downloaded anything for Mexico, so let me know if the data are of decent quality.

Good luck

**EDIT** -- Hi again.  I had a quick peek at that link I sent you.  It appears there may not be much data available at VDS beyond administrative boundaries & transportation networks (which I assume will include rail).  Another option to get the rest of your data for free is [The Geocommunity site.](http://data.geocomm.com/)  If you follow the link I sent, the process to get your data is very straightforward.

**A heads-up**, the data are rather coarse (read up before you use it ok).  You will however, find that there are more categories of data here.  You will have to sign up for an account, and you will get the data in an E00.zip format.  This is an old ArcInfo coverage file format, and you can use your conversion tools in ArcCatalog to convert it to a coverage.  If you've not done this before, follow the instructions [at this link](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/21052)

Cheers

**Addition RE: GeoCommunity**

They actually do have Mexico data there.

[image]

Comment: had not seen VDS yet, i added it to my resources for hard-to-find vector data

Comment: @ Sirgeo - I added some info to my answer.  Please give me some feedback regarding the data at VDS (as I'm curious) and you can get other categories of data at the other link I posted (although not the greatest of data!).

Comment: Thanks Dano, sorry for the delayed response. We use GeoCom for many US data downloads, didn't see any Mexico data there. VDS is a bit rough but definitely has some hard to find data. We went ahead and ordered the paper 50k Mexico topos from EastView for our project. We will scan and rubber sheet them as we have done in the past.

Comment: They do have Mexico data, but "nation-wide only" (see printscreen in original answer).  I must apologise.  I did not read carefully enough before posting my answer.  It appears you were looking for print ready maps, not Vector data sources.  I'll post the printscreen regardless.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

An excellent source for DRGs and more for Mexico: mexicomaps.com